# Can't copy executable files from network share to local disk

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

In my setup there is a win7 in a virtuialbox on a linux host. I like to use a "shared folder" with the host which is seen as "network location" in win7. Unfortunately I'm not able to execute some files from the shared folder (I want to put installer files there and install them in a lot of snapshots of my virtual machine). It's also not possible to copy the files to win7's local hard drive.

Error message for copying is: 
`An unexpected error is keeping you from copying the file...
Error 0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.`

Error message when trying to execute directly:
`The specified path does not exist. (I'm sure it exists because I just double-clicked the file.)`

I assume this is some kind of "security" setting but I could not find out how to disable this.